# How do you put a Thumbnail in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, thumbnails

I am trying to add Thumbnails to a custom post type ('wheels') admin page, and I am trying to do this with an array (see below).

The 'get_the_post-thumbnail' part of the array is giving me the problem, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-wheels_columns', 'asd_edit_wheels_columns' ) ;

function asd_edit_wheels_columns( $columns ) {

    $columns = array(
      'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
      'title' => __( 'Wheel Name' ),
      'rim_spokes' => __( '# Spokes' ),
      'wheel_tire' => __( 'Tire Name' ),
      'date' => __( 'Date' )
      'get_the_post-thumbnail [(post-thumbnail)'] => __( 'Featured' )
       );
    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem it's giving you?

Comment: What's wrong with it? What error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what exactly you are trying to do there (is this about some framework?), but I can see this one possible error:

```
'get_the_post-thumbnail [(post-thumbnail)'] => __( 'Featured' )
                                         ^^
```

At that point, you first close the quotation, and then you put the closing square bracket. This should give you a syntax error. I guess you wanted to include the bracket inside of the string, so you should switch the characters around.

#### edit:

Oh an also after `'date' => __( 'Date' )`, there is a comma (`,`) missing.

Comment: I am trying to insert the custom post type Thumbnail into the admin page columns. I tried you fix, and still get an error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /home/u7mtb69/public_html/wpsitehrhhw/wp-content/themes/hrhhw.1.1/functions.php on line 1009

Comment: function u7_edit_wheels_columns( $columns ) {

         $columns = array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title' => __( 'Wheel Name' ),
        'rim_spokes' => __( '# Spokes' ),
        'wheel_tire' => __( 'Tire Name' ),
        'date' => __( 'Date' )
                      'get_the_post-thumbnail [(post-thumbnail)]' => __( 'Featured' )

       );
       return $columns;
        }
        add_action( 'manage_wheels_posts_custom_column', 'u7_manage_wheels_columns', 10, 2 );
        function asd_manage_wheels_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
 global $post;
 switch( $column ) {

Comment: See my edited answer, if that doesn’t help please expand your *question* instead of posting additional information as comments.